# Bind Country to Ng2TelInput using dial code

Tags: angular, country-codes

I am using **Ng2TelInput** in my Angular 13 application and trying to bind the country code and phone number.

Html

```
 <div class="col-12">
    <div><label for="inputPhone" class="form-label">Phone</label></div>
    <input type="number" class="custom-tel-input form-control" ng2TelInput [ng2TelInputOptions]="ng2TelInputOptions"
                (countryChange)="onCountryChange($event)" formControlName="phone" ></div>
```

Ts

```
import { Ng2TelInput} from 'ng2-tel-input';

countryCode: string = "";
  countryCodeName: string = '';

  ng2TelInputOptions = {
    initialCountry: this.countryCodeName
  }
```

On form binding

```
 this.ng2TelInputOptions = { ...this.ng2TelInputOptions, initialCountry: obj["country_code"] };
  this.profileForm.setValue({
    firstName: obj["first_name"],
    lastName: obj["last_name"],
    username: obj["username"],
    email: obj["email"],
    phone: obj["phone_number"],
    countryCode: obj["country_code"],
  })
```

1. The country code was not displaying on form load. Is there any way so that I can get the country iso2 value using this country code in 'Ng2TelInput'?
2. Along with that padding style also collapsed for phonenumber field when i change it to Ng2TelInput.

[image]

For fixing this I have added css as

```
:host ::ng-deep .iti {
  width: 100%;
}

.iti--allow-dropdown {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

but both doesnt works as expected.